# How to run python interpreter in windows powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell-ise, python-interactive

According Microsoft, we can't run interactive console like python in it's own powershell ISE console. According to some sources it runs in the background. Can we run the same **python interpreter in foreground**?

Answer (score 5):

When people say it "runs in the background" they mean that when you try to run `Python` in ISE, it opens a legacy *console* app which ISE *illogically* hides (even though it can't bridge your actions to that app).

If you run a script which runs **and terminates**, that's fine, you can do that. You can, for instance, run `python --version` ...

But you can only start it interactively if you run it as a separate window using the `start-process` command: `start python`

Frankly, you'll have a lot better success interacting with PowerShell using the native console version of PowerShell.exe instead of ISE -- there, you can run python interactively and get the output into PowerShell without redirecting it through files.

Comment: thank you, Still is there any way around to get that? Or any solution to open multiple tabs in powershell.exe?

Comment: I use and recommend ConEmu, for tabs ;-) there's definitely not a workaround for running interactive console apps in ISE...